# Doctype over Meta X-UA-Compatibility

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, doctype

If I use `<!doctype html>`, do I have to use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` to prevent Internet Explorer's compatability message?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Which version of IE are you concerned about?

Comment: yes you can use both, for more [reference][1] [pls visit this link][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e

Answer (score 0):

Using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` will override such settings as "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" (which is enabled by default).  I've found using the meta tag is helpful when working on new pages which share a server with old (IE7 and older) pages, but I'm not sure if it's the preferred technique.